# edit styles for normal.dotm template

Tags: templates, ms-word

My intention is to edit the Normal.dotm file from word.
All the links i read and the examples talk about open the file in word, which opens as a template, add the styles that i want and save to use it later to create new documents.

In these examples, when i open the file with word, i never see the characters inside the normal.dotm.
When i open the file with (for example) notepad or wordpad, it shows rare characters that i cant read.

It is possible to edit manually(or directly) or add the styles in the text inside the file? or the only way possible is to add the styles when i open the file with word as a template?.

I think once i found a link that said it was incorrect to directly add text to that file manually. But i am not sure of that.

Can you give me some advice?. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the wrong forum for this type of question. SO is for questions about programming. In future please ask this sort of question on Super User.

To answer your question:

It is possible to edit Normal.dotm outside of Word but only if you are an expert in OOXML. If that is not the case open it inside Word using File | Open.

Documents in Word should be created from a template suited to the purpose, i.e. if you want to create letters first create a letter template with appropriate styles and content. You should not attempt to create all your documents based on the Normal template.